# MySQL "Convert" doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a database to CSV export function.
I'm using MySQL convert function to convert the date, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The error that I get is :-

```
string(140) "SELECT userid,firstname,lastname,email,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),registrationdate, 101) as registrationdate from users order by userid LIMIT 0,30" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(10),registrationdate, 101) as registrationdate from users order by user' at line 1
```

**Code**

```
<?php
include '../inc/inc.functions.php';
include '../dbconnector.php';
include '../dbpdo.php';
$query = "SELECT userid,firstname,lastname,email,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),registrationdate, 101) as registrationdate  from users order by userid LIMIT 0,30";
var_dump($query);
$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));

$array = array();

# Headers
$array[] = array("Serial Number","First Name","Last Name","Email","Registraion Date");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//    $array[] = $row;
    $array[] = array($row['userid'],$row['firstname'],$row['lastname'],$row['email'],$row['registrationdate']);
}
array_to_csv_download($array,"records.csv",",");

?>
```

What might be the problem? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you not using DATE_FORMAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have [CONVERT(..., 101)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), that's SQL Server's way of formatting datetimes.

In MySQL, you could use [`DATE_FORMAT('%m/%d/%Y', registrationdate)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format);

```
SELECT userid,firstname,lastname,email,
       DATE_FORMAT('%m/%d/%Y', registrationdate) as registrationdate 
       from users 
       order by userid 
       LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: @user3605847 Hm, I can't see a reason for that in your code. Is `registrationdate` non null in the database and spelled correctly in the `as` part of the query?

Comment: Yes, it's set to not null and spelled correctly as well.

Comment: @user3605847 Will the query run at a regular SQL prompt return the correct result?